# svn:global-ignores does not work for subdirectories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Suppose we have this directory structure:

> /root
>   /root/A
>   /root/A/A1
>   /root/A/A2
>   /root/A/A3

And if I set property `svn:global-ignores` on root to 'A1 A2' it ignored A1 and A2 folder as expected, but if I set `svn:global-ignores` to 'A2 A3' it do not ignore anything!

If I set svn:global-ignores to 'A1 A3' it ignores only A1, but it does not ignore A3.

Notice, this only for subdirectories (in my case 'A'). For folders in root directory it works as expected.

Where am I wrong? Or it is a bug in SVN?

SVN version: TortoiseSVN-1.9.4.27285-x64-svn-1.9.4.msi

Comment: Do you set those values in a single line?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have tried single line and multiple line.

Comment: I've tested your layout and I don't get anything at all ignored inside `A` unless I make `A` a versioned item. Even if actually ignored items come from system-wide global ignores, I can't explain your behaviour. (Please disregard my first and now deleted comment, I had totally misread your question.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, very interesting. I add A and then subdirectories. And now it works. So you need to add in order from parent to child. Starting to hate SVN, second day of use.

Comment: As of 2016, Subversion is probably only worth the effort if you've been already using it for some years and have a previous infrastructure you don't need/care to migrate to git. In any case, how global ignores work is just a tiny detail and it's probably due to the fact that neither you nor me have read the documentation carefully enough ;-)